# comparing $a^b$ and $b^a$ for arbitrary positive $a$ and $b$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Is there a way to compare $a^b$ and $b^a$? If  a,b both are greater the $e$( or  less than), then one may consider the function $f(x)=lnx/x$. But how to compare these two numbers in general?

Comment: You may wish to have a look here though it answers only part of your question- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771348/if-xy-yx-show-that-xy2e/1771441#1771441

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is stopping you from using $f$ on any pair of positive numbers. Actually, it's only if one number is larger than $e$ and one number is smaller you really need to use $f$.

If the two numbers are on the same side of $e$, then using the number closest to $e$ as base necessarily gives the largest result (although you would use $f$ to *prove* this).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You are right. But if the two numbers dont lie on the same side of e, what function is good to be considered?

Comment: I just said: the $f$ you have in your question works. Use whichever number makes $f$ largest as the base.

Answer (score 0):

There are the two well-known inequalities you mentioned.

In general it is impossible to compare these numbers:

$2>1$ and $2^1>1^2$

$5>2$ and $5^2<2^5$

$2\neq 4$ but $2^4=4^2$

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question.