# If $1 < x < e < y$ and $x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$ then $y > e^2/x$.

Tags: inequality, power-series, lambert-w

If $1 < x < e < y$
and
$x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$
then
$y > e^2/x$.

Since
$x^{1/x}$
is decreasing for
$x > e$,
this is equivalent to
$x^{1/x}
\lt (e^2/x)^{x/e^2}
$for $1 < x < e$.

Also, it would be nice
to find a closer approximation
to $y$ than
$e^2/x$.

Also $^2$,
I realize that
this might be better solved
using the Lambert-W function.

So,
if you want to make a question of this,
it could either be
"Is there a simpler prrof
of this result"
or
"Is there a better bound for
the $y > e$
with $x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}$
than $e^2/x$"?

$f(x)
=\dfrac{x^{1/x}}{(e^2/x)^{x/e^2}}
$
with
$1 < x < e$.

Want to show
$f(x) <1 $.

This proof is
much more involved than I like.

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=\ln(f(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)\ln(e^2/x)\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)(\ln(e^2)-\ln(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)+(x/e^2)\ln(x)\\
&=(1/x+x/e^2)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)\\
&=(e^{-y}+e^y/e^2)y-(2e^y/e^2)
\qquad x = e^y, 0 < y < 1\\
&=(e^{-y}+e^{y-2})y-2e^{y-2}\\
&=e^{-1}(e^{-y+1}+e^{y-1})y-2e^{y-2}\\
&=\dfrac{2y}{e}\dfrac{e^{-y+1}+e^{y-1}}{2}-2e^{y-2}\\
&=\dfrac{2y}{e}\cosh(-y+1)-\dfrac{2}{e}e^{y-1}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}(y\cosh(-y+1)-e^{y-1})\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}((1-z)\cosh(z)-e^{-z})
\qquad z = 1-y, y = 1-z, 0 < z < 1\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}h(z)
\qquad h(z)=(1-z)\cosh(z)-e^{-z}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left((1-z)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nz^n}{n!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{e}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{2n+1}(1-(2n+1))}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=-\dfrac{2}{e}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&\lt 0
\qquad\text{for } z > 0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g(x) < 0$
so $f(x) < 1$.

Therefore,
if $r(x) = x^{1/x}$,
then,
if $1 < x < e$,
$r(x)
\lt r(e^2/x)
$.

Since $e^2/x > e$,
if
$e < y \le  e^2/x$,
$r(y)
\ge r(e^2/x)
\gt r(x)
$.

Therefore,
if $1 < x < e < y \le e^2/x$,
or $1 < x < e$
and $xy \le e^2$
then
$r(y) > r(x)
$.

Therefore if
$r(y) = r(x)$
then
$y > e^2/x$.

Comment: for $a>1$,and $a\ne e$  the equation $$x^a=a^x$$
has 2 solutions, one greater the $e$ and one less than $e$. You could try to show that the product of the solutions is greater than $e^2$.

Comment: two related problems: [P1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771348/if-xy-yx-show-that-xy2e), [P2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995517/prove-x-1y-1e-12-where-xy-yx-yx0)

Comment: I am not sure if the Lambert W function helps prove that $xy>e^2$ but perhaps it does help solve the general question of comparing $a^b$ and $b^a.$ Perhaps someone will know what to do. If $1<a<e<b$ and $a^{1/a}=c^{1/c}$ for some $c>e,$ then $c=e^{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{a}\right)}=-\frac{a}{\ln(a)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\ln(a)}{a}\right).$ Then we compare b and c which is probably easier said than done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a := \frac{y}{x} > 1$.

From $x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$, we have $x^{y/x} = y$ and
$x^a = ax$ and $x^{a-1} = a$ which results in
$$x = a^{\frac{1}{a-1}}. \tag{1}$$
Then, we have
$$y = a x = a^{\frac{a}{a-1}}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), we have
$$xy = a^{\frac{1}{a-1}} \cdot a^{\frac{a}{a-1}} = a^{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}.\tag{3}$$

It suffices to prove that
$$a^{\frac{a+1}{a-1}} > \mathrm{e}^2$$
or
$$F(a) := \ln a - \frac{2(a-1)}{a+1} > 0.$$

We have
$$F'(a) = \frac{(a-1)^2}{a(a+1)^2}.$$
Thus, $F'(1) = 0$, and $F'(a) > 0$ for all $a > 1$.
Also, $F(1) = 0$. Thus, we have $F(a) > 0$ for all $a > 1$.

We are done.

Comment: In my opinion, it's the best proof here.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks.

Comment: I agree. It's nice to see a different use for that standard parameterization of $x^y=y^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $s=\log x$ and $t=\log y$, and defining $f(u) = u/e^u$, allows us to change this multiplicative statement into an additive statement: If $0<s<1<t$ and $f(s)=f(t)$, then $s+t>2$. This will allow us to more easily use convexity-type arguments.

We may certainly assume that $t\le2$ or else the conclusion is trivially true. To prove the statement, write
$$
0 = f(t) - f(s) = \int_s^t f'(u)\,du = \int_s^{2-t} f'(u)\,du + \int_{2-t}^1 f'(u)\,du + \int_1^t f'(u)\,du.
$$
(Note that the first integral is well defined no matter what under the usual convention $\int_s^{2-t} f'(u)\,du = -\int_{2-t}^s f'(u)\,du$.) Equivalently,
\begin{align*}
\int_{2-t}^s f'(u)\,du &= \int_{2-t}^1 f'(u)\,du + \int_1^t f'(u)\,du \\
&= - \int_t^1 f'(2-v)\,dv + \int_1^t f'(u)\,du = \int_1^t \bigl( f'(v) + f'(2-v) \bigr) \,dv. \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
Now note that $f'''(u) = (3-u)e^{-u}$, which is positive for $0\le u\le 2$. Therefore $f'(u)$ is strictly convex on $[0,2]$. In particular, for all $v\in(1,2)$,
$$
\frac{f'(v) + f'(2-v)}2 > f'\biggl( \frac{v+(2-v)}2 \biggr) = f'(1) = 0.
$$
Therefore the integrand on the right-hand side of ($*$) is always positive, and the endpoints of integration are in the "right order" ($t>1$); it follows that the integral is itself positive, so that ($*$) implies
$$
\int_{2-t}^s f'(u)\,du > 0.
$$
On the other hand, $f'(u) = (1-u)e^{-u}$ is always positive for $0<u<1$, and so we conclude that the endpoints of this integral are also in the "right order", meaning that $2-t<s$—which is the inequality $s+t>2$ we want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this
much simpler proof.

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=\ln(f(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)\ln(e^2/x)\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(x/e^2)(\ln(e^2)-\ln(x))\\
&=(1/x)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)+(x/e^2)\ln(x)\\
\\
g(e)
&=(1/e)\ln(e)-(2e/e^2)+(e/e^2)\ln(e)\\
&=0\\
\\
g'(x)
&=((1/x)\ln(x)-(2x/e^2)+(x/e^2)\ln(x))'\\
&=\dfrac{(x^2-e^2) (\ln(x) - 1)}{e^2 x^2}
\qquad\text{(according to Wolfram Alpha)}\\
&>0
\qquad \text{for } 1 < x < e\\
\\
g'(e)
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g(x) < g(e)
=0$
for $1 < x < e$.